# Grails with Comet working example

Tags: grails, comet, server-push, cometd, bayeux

I'm trying to implement server [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) in Grails application using [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) by working out few simple examples, but I'm struggling to make it really work.  I've been trying out 2 examples from the below 2 links and it is not working.  Not working in the sense, am not able to see the expected result, though I don't get any errors/exceptions.

- [Using Cometd 2.x with Grails](http://metasieve.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/using-cometd-2-x-with-grails/)
- [Grails-based Comet (Bayeux Protocol)](http://www.jroller.com/wiradikusuma/entry/grails_based_comet_bayeux_protocol)

Any help in the form of working example, pointers, links, suggestions, etc. are really appreciated.

**NOTE:** As you can see from above posts, the article is 2-3 years old. Currently, I'm running Grails v2.1.0 and [cometd plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/cometd) is v0.2.2. IDE is NetBeans v7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for server push technology using Grails [Events Push Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/events-push), though, instead of Cometd / Bayeux.

Following links were helpful in implementing server push technology:

1. [Grails with Comet working example](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-with-Comet-working-example-td4637565.html)
2. [Issue with grails events push plugin](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Issue-with-grails-events-push-plugin-td4633074.html)
3. Example of Events-Push in action in the [SpringOne2GX](http://www.springsource.org/SpringOne2GX2012) Day 1 Keynote video by Graeme (goto 1:06 in the video)

Comment: In *conf/BuildConfig.groovy*, an entry of `grails.tomcat.nio = true` is required for this server push to work properly.